# Retrieve String data from a textfile and store it pack to an object

Tags: java, string, while-loop, dao

In my code example you will se a lot of code.

However, the problem lies within the restoreCourse method (in the end of the code), where I'm trying to restore all the data (that have been retrieved from StorageManager) into my string array (named lineBuffer) and then use that data to restore an object of the class Course and return it in the end of the method.

```
public class Course {

private String name;
private int courseID;
private String signUpCode;
private String courseGuide;
private String courseScheme;
private String courseGrade;
private String courseSpeed;
private String courseCredit;

public Course(String name,int courseID,String signUpCode,
        String courseGuide,String courseScheme,String courseSpeed,String 
courseCredit){
    this.name = name;
    this.courseID = courseID;
    this.signUpCode= signUpCode;
    this.courseGuide = courseGuide;
    this.courseScheme = courseScheme;
    this.courseSpeed = courseSpeed;
    this.courseCredit = courseCredit;
    this.courseGrade = "";
}
public int getCourseID(){
    return courseID;
}
public String getCourseName(){
    return name;
}
public String getSignUpCode(){
    return signUpCode;
}
public String getCourseScheme(){
    return courseScheme;
}
public String getCourseGuide(){
    return courseGuide;
}
public String getCourseGrade(){
    return courseGrade;
}
public String getCourseSpeed(){
    return courseSpeed;
}
public String getCourseCredit(){
    return courseCredit;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer();
    msg.append (courseID);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (name);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (signUpCode);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (courseGuide);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (courseScheme);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (courseGrade);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (courseSpeed);
    msg.append ("-");
    msg.append (courseCredit);
    msg.append ("\n");
    return msg.toString();
}
}


public class FileCourseDAO implements CourseDAO {

public void  saveCourse(Course course){     

    StringBuffer dataBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseID());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseName());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getSignUpCode());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseGuide());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseScheme());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseGrade());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseSpeed());
    dataBuffer.append ("-");
    dataBuffer.append (course.getCourseCredit());
    dataBuffer.append ("\n");

    StorageManager packer = StorageManager.getInstance();

    try {
        packer.storeStringData (dataBuffer.toString().trim());
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println ("Storage manager Error:");
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
}


public Course  restoreCourse(int courseID){
    StorageManager packer = StorageManager.getInstance();

    if (!packer.storeExists ()){
        System.out.println ("No file with data.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        String[] lineBuffer = null;
        List<String> dataBuffer = packer.readData();

        for (String dataLine : dataBuffer){
            lineBuffer = dataLine.split(" ");   
        }



    Course course = new Course ();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println ("Error while reading data file.");
    }
    return course;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You seem to have to have a lot of unnecessary code.Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is the issue you are facing

Comment: I would like to restore the object (that I saved inside the method "saveCourse" as a textfile) and return the object, by using the method "restoreCourse".

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to restore the object (that I saved inside the method "saveCourse" as a textfile) and return the object, by using the method "restoreCourse".

- in the method `saveCourse` you serialized the course fields delimited by `-`; so when splitting that string you have to use `dataLine.split("-")` instead of `dataLine.split(" ")`.
- You are creating an instance of `Course` class and returning it without initializing. After splitting use these data to initialize your course object and return it to the caller.

The following code might work:

```
public Course  restoreCourse(int courseID){
    StorageManager packer = StorageManager.getInstance();

    if (!packer.storeExists ()){
        System.out.println ("No file with data.");
        return;
    }
    Course course = null;
    try {
        String[] lineBuffer = null;
        List<String> dataBuffer = packer.readData();

        for (String dataLine : dataBuffer){
            lineBuffer = dataLine.split("-");
            if (lineBuffer.length > 7 && courseID == lineBuffer[0]) {
                course = new Course(lineBuffer[1],lineBuffer[0],lineBuffer[2], lineBuffer[3],lineBuffer[4],lineBuffer[6],lineBuffer[7] ); 
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println ("Error while reading data file.");
    }
    return course;
}
```

Note:
Take care of the order of constructor parameter and the order of the fields in the `saveCourse()` method (they are not in the same order); I tried to match them but check yourself if they are in the right order

Comment: Thanks! It made the code much better. I also converted the integer (the parameter that the method takes) to a string, so you can find it in the linebuffer. And then reconverted it to an integer again, before adding it to the Course constructor.

However, If we assume that we store 10 different objects inside the textfile, how would you identify the index of the integer and then retrieve all the other 6 indexes for that object? That will be placed inside the constructor of Course, before returning it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. what do you mean by `index of the integer`?

Comment: Each object of the class Course have a courseID (that is an integer number). Now, if I have stored 10 objects of the class Course inside a text file, and I would only like to restore a specific object (with help of the courseID). How would you find that specific courseID number, together with the rest of the attributes that belongs to that object, and restore the object.     In the code example you gave me we assume theres only one object in the text file, but imagine if we had 10 different objects.

Comment: In the code we are not assuming that there is only one course object. Look at the `for` loop. It is iterating over all the lines representing a course object (these can be 10 or 20 or 100 ...) and selecting only the one whose `courseID` is passed to the method. The `if`statement in the loop is doing exactly that. Once we found the line belonging to the `courseID`, we create an instance of the `Course` class and return it.